# How to get all types from an interface without the [key:string]:any

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface whith this strucure:

```
interface Parent {
  child_1: number;
  child_2: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

I have a function that looks like:

```
const func = <T,>(children: Children<T>) => {/* Do stuff with T children*/}
```

**So my question is, what is the best way to describe the type for the children if I want to omit the [key:string]: any?**

My current setup works, but Im sure there are some Typescript wizards out there that can find improvements.

```
type NoStringIndex<U> = {
  [K in keyof U as string extends K ? never : K]: U[K];
};
type Children<T> = NoStringIndex<T>[keyof NoStringIndex<T>];

const func = <T,>(children: Children<T>) => {/* Do stuff with T children*/}
```

The problem here is that:

```
func<Parent>("hej");
```

Is that the underlying types are lost when I hover the function:
`const func: <Parent>(children: Children<Parent>) => void`

If I instead do:

```
type NoStringIndex<U> = {
  [K in keyof U as string extends K ? never : K]: U[K];
};

const func =<T,>( children:NoStringIndex<T>[keyof NoStringIndex<T>]) =>{/* Do stuff with T children*/}
```

I get the types of the children when I hover the function in my IDE.

```
const func: <Parent>(children: string | number) => void
```

But I now have NoStringIndex[keyof NoStringIndex] in multiple places in my code, which is not the prettiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just concerned about the lengthy boilerplate then perhaps a helper type like

```js
type WithoutStringIndex<U> =
  NoStringIndex<U>[keyof NoStringIndex<U>] | never

const func = <T,>(children: WithoutStringIndex<T>) =>{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: How is that different from what I did try with Children<T>?

Comment: It's somewhat briefer in terms of boilerplate while still keeping intellisense happy which is why I prefaced it with that "if you're concerned" bit. I'm not sure what you're asking for here – you can keep the index signature in the standard type and remove it, or omit the signature from the standard type and then add it back where you need it. Perhaps you could elaborate on your hopes here?

Comment: Sorry for doubting you. Now that I actually tried your solution, it is more or less what I was after. Unless there is a cleaner way to do the same thing. So thank you!
Though I do not understand how "| never"  solves the problem. Do you know why or have  some article that you could point to?

Comment: I couldn't say precisely but it's working around TS's heuristics for [preserving type aliases](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42284). You could get a similar result with e.g. `NoStringIndex<U>[keyof NoStringIndex<U>] extends infer T ? T : never`, which encourages TS to resolve `T`. I suspect it's heuristics all the way down but I'm no expert.